# Prolog - find words in matrix

Tags: prolog

Given an `nxn` letter matrix and a list of words, the program should find all the appearances of the words in the matrix and their location.

They could appear up-down, right-left and diagonally (over all 8 directions). A word can appear any number of times (including zero) and they can overlap (like the words `bad`, and `adult`) and even be a subset of one another (like the words `bad` and `ad`).

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the "my friend" thing. Your SO reputation speaks for itself that you've made a lot of contributions here.

Comment: @Greg Harman you pretty much made my day, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** Here's a complete code (finds words in diagonals too).  One drawback: words from the main diagonals are found twice.

```
% word(X) iff X is a word
word("foo").
word("bar").
word("baz").

% prefix(?A, +B) iff A is a prefix of B
prefix([], _).
prefix([A|B], [A|C]) :- prefix(B, C).

% sublist(?A, +B) iff A is a sublist of B
sublist(A, B) :- prefix(A, B).
sublist(A, [_|B]) :- sublist(A, B).

% reversed(?A, +B) iff A is reversed B
reversed(A, B) :- reversed(B, [], A).
reversed([A|B], C, D) :- reversed(B, [A|C], D).
reversed([], A, A).

% rowsreversed(?A, +B) iff matrix A is matrix B with reversed rows
rowsreversed([A|B], [C|D]) :- reversed(A, C), rowsreversed(B, D).
rowsreversed([], []).

% transposed(+A, ?B) iff matrix B is transposed matrix A
transposed(A, B) :- transposed(A, [], B).
transposed(M, X, X) :- empty(M), !.
transposed(M, A, X) :- columns(M, Hs, Ts), transposed(Ts, [Hs|A], X).

% empty(+A) iff A is empty list or a list of empty lists
empty([[]|A]) :- empty(A).
empty([]).

% columns(+M, ?Hs, ?Ts) iff Hs is the first column
%   of matrix M and Ts is the rest of matrix M
columns([[Rh|Rt]|Rs], [Rh|Hs], [Rt|Ts]) :- columns(Rs, Hs, Ts).
columns([[]], [], []).
columns([], [], []).

% inmatrix(+M, ?W) iff word W is in the matrix M
inmatrix(M, W) :- inrows(M, W).
inmatrix(M, W) :- incolumns(M, W).
inmatrix(M, W) :- inleftdiagonals(M, W).
inmatrix(M, W) :- inrightdiagonals(M, W).

% inrows(+M, ?W) iff W or reversed W is in a row of M
inrows([R|_], W) :- word(W), sublist(W, R).
inrows([R|_], W) :- word(W), reversed(V, W), sublist(V, R).
inrows([_|Rs], W) :- inrows(Rs, W).

% incolumns(+M, ?W) iff W or reversed W is in a column of M
incolumns(M, W) :- transposed(M, N), inrows(N, W).

% inleftdiagonals(+M, ?W) iff W or reversed W is in a left diagonal of M
inleftdiagonals(M, W) :- inupperleftdiagonals(M, W).
inleftdiagonals(M, W) :- transposed(M, N), inupperleftdiagonals(N, W).

% inupperleftdiagonals(+M, ?W) iff W or reversed W is in an upper left diagonal of M
inupperleftdiagonals(M, W) :- upperdiags(M, N), inrows(N, W).

% upperdiags(+M, ?X) iff X is a list of upper diagonals of matrix M
upperdiags(M, X) :- upperdiags(M, [], Y), reversed(Z, Y), transposed(Z, X).
upperdiags([R|Rs], A, X) :- columns(Rs, _, T), upperdiags(T, [R|A], X).
upperdiags([], X, X).

% inrightdiagonals(+M, ?W) iff W or reversed W is in a right diagonal of M
inrightdiagonals(M, W) :- rowsreversed(N, M), inleftdiagonals(N, W).
```

Comment: Sorry for the inconsistent order of in & out parameters.  It's late and I'm sure I'll make mots of listakes if I try to swap them right now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a partial solution for horizontal and vertical straight and reverse lookup:

```
count_hits(Word, Matrix, Result):-
        atom_chars(Word, Chars),
        reverse(Chars, C2),
        transpose_matrix(Matrix, M2),
        findall(1, find_chars_in_matrix(Chars,Matrix), A),
        findall(1, find_chars_in_matrix(Chars,M2), B),
        findall(1, find_chars_in_matrix(C2,Matrix), C),
        findall(1, find_chars_in_matrix(C2,M2), D),
        length(A, X1),
        length(B, X2),
        length(C, X3),
        length(D, X4),
        Result is X1 + X2 + X3 + X4.

transpose_matrix([],[]).
transpose_matrix([[ULCorner|Header]|Body], [[ULCorner|NewHeader]|NewBody]) :- 
        collect_heads_and_tails(Body, NewHeader, Kernel),
        collect_heads_and_tails(NewBody, Header, X2),
        transpose_matrix(Kernel, X2).

collect_heads_and_tails([], [], []).
collect_heads_and_tails([[H|T]|TT], [H|X], [T|Y]):-collect_heads_and_tails(TT, X, Y).

find_chars_in_matrix(Chars, [H|_]):-
        sublist(Chars, H).

find_chars_in_matrix(Chars, [_|T]):-
        find_chars_in_matrix(Chars, T).

sublist(L, [_|T]) :- sublist(L, T).
sublist(A, B) :- prefix(A, B).

prefix([H|T], [H|T2]) :- prefix(T, T2).
prefix([], _).


% test data
matrix([[e,t,r,e],
        [r,r,t,r],
        [t,r,t,t],
        [e,e,t,e]]).
go :- matrix(M), count_hits(etre, M, X), write(X).
:-go.
```

Two weaknesses: (a) palindromic words are found twice, and one-letter words are found four times - mathematically justifiable, but probably unwanted from a common-sense perspective. (b) diagonal matches aren't found at all, for that you need more involved recursion with at least one additional counting argument.

Full disclosure: transpose_matrix/2 was adapted from the beautiful answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897632/prolog-list-question)   question. It's amazing, the wealth of code that stackoverflow has accumulated in just two years...