# transpose a matrix in prolog

Tags: matrix, prolog, transpose

I'm fairly new to Prologue and one of my first assignments in the class is to transpose a matrix in Prolog, meaning: If I have a matrix

```
A=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I should get another matrix

```
S=[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]].
```

I've written the code for it, however in the result I'm getting something like:

```
S=[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9], []].
```

(There is an empty list at the end of it).
How do I correct something like that? Is my code completely wrong? I'm not supposed to use any non-standard tools (such as SWI-Prolog)

```
trans([],[]).
trans([S|R], [L|L1]) :-
    trans(S, R, L, M),
    trans(M, L1).

trans([], _,[],[]).
trans([S1|S2], [], [S1|L1], [S2|M]):-
    trans([], [], L1, M).
trans([S1|S2], [R1|R2], [S1|L1], [S2|M]):-
    trans(R1, R2, L1, M).
```

I've also seen and used the code provided here: [How to transpose a matrix in prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280986/how-to-transpose-a-matrix-in-prolog?rq=1) , however I wanted to try and write it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is to add another rule for predicate `trans/2` to match that specific situation that in your case adds the empty list at the end.

```
trans([],[]).
trans([[]|_], []):-!.
trans([S|R], [L|L1]) :-
    trans(S, R, L, M),
    trans(M, L1).
```