# How to change an order of list of lists

Tags: prolog

I have a list of substitutions between variables and values
they are presented in a list `[[x,y],[1,2]]` (meaning that the value of `x` equals `1`, and the value of `y` equals `2`).
I want to change the list to a list of pairs meaning `[[x,1],[y,2]]`,
I tried to use `append` so that I will create a pair in each step of the recursion and append it to a new list but i have problem of doing so (mainly selecting the head and tails of each pair)

Comment: Can you show your attempt(s) at a solution? Or just use [transpose/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=transpose/2).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to transpose a matrix in prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280986/how-to-transpose-a-matrix-in-prolog)

Comment: @lurker: Hehe, how right you are!

Answer (score 0):

your example it's a bit contrived, but transpose it's a bit overkill, specially if you're going to implement yourself. I think this should solve your need

```
'change an order of list of lists'([X_Y_Z, A_B_C], XA_YB_ZC) :-
    findall([K, V], (nth1(I, X_Y_Z, K), nth1(I, A_B_C, V)), XA_YB_ZC).
```